# Scrolling list in Android home screen widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying to teach myself the basics of Android dev. At the moment I am experimenting with home screen widgets. I would like to create a simple widget that lists all my bookmarks. Somewhere in my googling I read that ListView is not usable in a widget. What's the best way to display a scrolling list in a widget? An example would be fantastic, but otherwise point me in the right general direction and I can research further.

Thanks in advance,
Dany.

Comment: Oh, forgot to add - I come from a .NET background and am trying to get into the Android mindset. My immediate thought is to have the equivalent of a .NET usercontrol, and add it to the layout container for each item to be displayed in the list. That doesn't sound quite right in terms of Android though - can this actually be achieved? Is there a concept of usercontrol or reusable control in Android?

Answer (score 1):

ListViews are supported in Custom Launchers that support the scrollable-widgets extension or in the Launchers since Android 3.0 (Honeycomb). Take the Android Agenda Widget for example, this supports scrolling in Custom Launchers, or the GMail-widget on Honeycomb.

Scrolling widgets in Custom Launchers is described here:
http://www.geekrono.com/2010/08/android-scrollable-widgets.html

Scrolling widgets in Honeycomb and up is described here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#collections

You can finnd the sources for good working example except for Honeycomb at http://code.google.com/p/scrollablecontacts/

Answer (score 0):

I've only seen a huge list widget on phones with HTC Sense - [example](http://www.androidauthority.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/htc-widget-history.jpg). HTC Sense has a widget like that for Stocks, Twitter, etc. I don't think it's a good idea to develop huge widgets like that, because they take up too much space and some phones are limited to 3 screens (screens that you can put your app shortcuts, widgets and etc).

This is a good article on Widget UI Patterns:
[Widget Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html)

Seesmic for Android has a 'list' widget with latest tweets:[Seesmic Blog](http://blog.seesmic.com/2010/04/seesmic-for-android-widget-geotagging-native-retweet.html)
[Widget Screen](http://seesmic.typepad.com/.a/6a00e54fa7655b88330133eccae967970b-800wi)

There's also an article on UI Patterns, based on the new Twitter app, hope that helps you - [Link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/twitter-for-android-closer-look-at.html) and a [video](http://code.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/android-ui-design-patterns.html) (Android UI design patterns).

Re: user controls (like in .NET), [Android Views](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html) and in your case 'ListView' is what you might use for your app. You also mentioned .NET (Visual Studio), you might be interested in [MOTODEV Studio](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio/). It's basically a better version of Eclipse (with Android SDK) that has common code snippets and other cool stuff.

Comment: Thanks - I have downloaded MOTODEV Studio and am checking it out right now.

This is mostly a learning experience for me, but also something that's useful. It's unlikely the widget will make it to the market any time soon if I get around to finishing it. Mostly it is for my own benefit. As far as I know ListView cannot be used in a widget - can you confirm this?